# Create New Variable by Matching from adjacent Column to another data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Looking for a more elegant solution using `data.table` code to accomplish the following:

I have two data tables, which can be captured by the following example:

```
library("data.table")
A <- data.table(country_name = c("afghanistan", "albania", "algeria"),
                country_rank = c(1:3))                                 #primary data table
B <- data.table(country_name = c("afghanistan", "albania", "algeria"),
                A2 = c("AF", "AL", "DZ"))                            #reference data table

A
#     country_name country_rank
# 1:  afghanistan            1
# 2:      albania            2
# 3:      algeria            3

B
#    country_name A2
# 1:  afghanistan AF
# 2:      albania AL
# 3:      algeria DZ
```

I would like to add a new column to A that is the 2-letter country code, contained in B.  I am accomplishing this currently using `dplyr`, and what I feel is a quite convoluted manner; reading the command is unnecessarily confusing, I feel.  I am wondering the analog solution within `data.table`.

FYI Within dplyr:

```
A <- mutate(A, A2 = B[match(A$country_name, B$country_name), A2])
A
   country_name country_rank A2
1:  afghanistan            1 AF
2:      albania            2 AL
3:      algeria            3 DZ
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.table` is set up to do these joins very naturally, but you need to specify the common key first.

```
setkey(A, country_name)
setkey(B, country_name)

A[B] ## join A with B on the common key 'country_name'
   country_name country_rank A2
1:  afghanistan            1 AF
2:      albania            2 AL
3:      algeria            3 DZ
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join in dplyr to do as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(A, B)
Joining by: "country_name"
  country_name country_rank A2
1  afghanistan            1 AF
2      albania            2 AL
3      algeria            3 DZ
```

You can use `select` to relocate the last column where you need.

If `B` does not have all the country names, you can use `left_join` instead to get `NAs` into the missing rows.